# Where do I add the Google Analytics Tracking Code in a Nova app sor that it trigger on each route change

Tags: php, google-analytics, laravel-nova

When I install my Google Analytics Tracking Code in my `layout.blade.php` or `footer.blade.php`, the tracker fire only once on the page load.

Laravel Nova is acting as a Single Page Application and does not fire the PageView when the route change.

Where should I put the tracking code so that it trigger on each route change?

Comment: I have this same issue, looking foward for some help. If I resolve this issue I'll post it here. Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 1):

It does not depend on the position where you enter the code. A single page application must be tracked in a specific way, it is not enough to insert the base code on the page. You must use the virtual pages:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications